# Create odd function from arbitrary function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I have a product of two arbitrary functions $f$ and $g$,
$$y(x) = f(x)g(x)$$
and I want to make the product $y$ odd. I know $f$, e.g. it's a typical Lorentzian function
$$f(x) = \dfrac{b}{(x-a)+b^2},$$
but I want to deduce $g$.

What strategy can I use to find $g$?

**Context:** I want to start by assuming that these functions are well behaved, defined in real space, and differentiable everywhere. How would I find $g$ so that the product $fg$ becomes odd? Then my goal is to make $f$ more complex (e.g. multiplying the Lorentzian above with the discontinuous [Bose-Einstein distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics), for example) then see if it's still possible to make $fg$ an odd function.

This [reference](http://blog.mathteachersresource.com/?tag=creating-even-or-odd-functions-from-an-arbitrary-function) summarises odd/even functions but I didn't find it too helpful for my problem.

Comment: Are there any given properties of these functions like domain, continuity, differentiability, analyticity, etc.? As general as you have it right now, I feel it you would be hard-pressed to come up with a 'general' strategy for finding $g$, if such a function even exists.

Comment: These functions are well behaved, defined in real space, and differentiable everywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so, of course there are *lots* of options here. The simplest, but unsatisfying, would be to make $g$ be $\frac{1}{f(x)}x$, so that $y$ is just $x$. What that example  demonstrates is that there's just *way* too little information here to pin down one specific $g$.

But one that might be more satisfying would be to take $g(x) = xf(-x)$. This has the advantage of retaining some of the "character" of $f$, but without knowing more about your goal here I can't tell if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: $g(x)=xf(−x)$ looks like an interesting choice... I have provided more context on my problem above.

Comment: @MedullaOblongata $xf(-x)$ will work for any function $f$ that has the properties you want. If you make $f$ discontinuous, though, I don't think you can guarantee that there exists a continuous $g$.

Answer (score 5):

Odd and even functions behave exactly the same way under multiplication as odd and even numbers (hence the terminology). In particular,

- an odd function times an odd function is even
- an even function times an even function is even
- an odd function times an even function is odd

It might help to know a little bit more about the function $f$. If it's a Lorentzian *centred on zero*, then it's even, and any odd function $g$ will suffice to make $y$ odd. If it never takes the value zero, then we can take $g$ to be $1/f$ multiplied by any odd function. Trivially we can always just take $g = 0$ and $y$ will be odd (and, incidentally, even).

Comment: I updated my question - $f$ is a general Lorentzian function so it doesn't have to be centered on zero.

Answer (score 4):

Let $e(x) = \frac{1}{2}(f(x) + f(-x))$ and write
$$  o(x) = f(x) - e(x)  \text{.}  $$
That is, let $e$ be the even part of $f$ and $o$ be the odd part of $f$.

Then let $g(x) = \frac{o(x)}{f(x)}$ so that $y(x) = f(x) \frac{o(x)}{f(x)}$.  This is undefined anywhere $f$ is zero, but $f(x) = \frac{b}{(x-a)^2+b^2}$ (which only differs from the [Cauchy/Lorentzian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) distribution by a normalizing factor) is always positive, as long as $b \neq 0$ (which seems likely).

Following the above prescription, 
$$  o(x) = \frac{2 a b x}{a^4 + 2a^2(b-x)(b+x) + (b^2 + x^2)^2} $$
and
$$  g(x) = \frac{2 a x}{b^2 + (x+a)^2}  \text{.}  $$

As others have noted, there are many other ways to select $g$, but this one picks out an intrinsic property of $f$ (its odd part), so may capture some other property that you want but have not specifically called out.